# How does Spark handle partial cache/persist results?

Tags: apache-spark

If you cache a very large dataset that cannot be all stored in memory or on disk how does spark handle the partial cache? how does it know which data needs to be recomputed when you go to use that dataframe again?

Example:

1. Read 100 GB dataset into memory `df1`
2. Compute new dataframe `df2` based on `df1`
3. cache `df2`

If spark can only fit 50GB of Cache for `df2` what happens if you go to reuse `df2` for the next steps? How would spark know which data it doesn't need to recompute and which is does? Will it need to re-read that data again that it couldn't persist?

UPDATE

What happens if you have 5GB memory and 5GB disk and try to cache a 20GB dataset? What happens to the other 10GB of data that can't be cached and how does spark know which data it needs to recompute and which it doesn't?

Comment: Spark uses partitions, hard to answer your question. May be add your comments to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Spark has this *default* option for DF and DS:

> MEMORY_AND_DISK – This is the default behavior of the DataFrame or
> Dataset. In this Storage Level, The DataFrame will be stored in JVM
> memory as a deserialized objects. When required storage is greater
> than available memory, it stores some of the excess partitions into
> local disk and reads the data from local disk when it required. It is slower as
> there is I/O involved.

However, to be more specific:

> Spark's unit of processing is a partition = 1 task. So the discussion
> is more about partition or partitions fitting into memory and/or local
> disk.
>
> If a partition of the DF doesn't fit in memory and disk when using
> StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK, then the OS will fail, aka kill, the
> Executor / Worker. Eviction of other partitions than your own DF may occur, but
> not for your own DF. The `.cache` is either successful or not, there is no re- reading in this case.
>
> I base this on the fact that partition eviction does not occur for partitions belonging to the same underlying RDD. Not well explained all this stuff, but see here: [How does Spark evict cached partitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660385/how-does-spark-evict-cached-partitions). In the end other RDD partitions may be evicted and re-computed but in the end also yo need enough local disk as well as memory.

A good read is: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-difference-between-cache-and-persist/

Comment: Hi - so I am aware of the memory/disk options. My question was: what happens if you have 5GB memory and 5GB disk and try to cache a 20GB dataset? What happens to the other 10GB of data that can't be cached and how does spark know which data it needs to recompute and which it doesnt

Comment: It will fail you need enuff memory and disk